# Does Retrofit support rx.Future/Task/Async/Single?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2

I've found nice example of usage RxJava at [this article](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/getting-started-with-rxjava-and-android):

```
Subscription subscription = Single.create(new Single.OnSubscribe() {
           @Override
           public void call(SingleSubscriber singleSubscriber) {
               String value = longRunningOperation();
               singleSubscriber.onSuccess(value);
           }
       })
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .subscribe(new Action1() {
           @Override
           public void call(String value) {
               // onSuccess
               Snackbar.make(rootView, value, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       }, new Action1() {
           @Override
           public void call(Throwable throwable) {
               // handle onError
           }
       });
```

But since I am using Retrofit I would like to create RetrofitService and use Single class to combine the result of two requests to backend into one dataset, as described:

> When subscribing to a Single, there is only an onSuccess Action and an
>   onError action. The Single class has a different set of operators than
>   Observable, with several operators that allow for a mechanism of
>   converting a Single to an Observable. For example, using the
>   Single.mergeWith() operator, two or more Singles of the same type can
>   be merged together to create an Observable, emitting the results of
>   each Single to one Observable.

Is it possible to achieve this (and how)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, see [Retrofit Adapters](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit-adapters%2FREADME.md)
Only worked with Retrofit2.0